# Copper Mozilla plugin doesn't work on 56.0.1 (64 bit)

Tags: mozilla, coap

I installed Copper on Mozilla version 56.0.1 but it didn't show up any Copper GUI.

Comment: Your question doesn’t look like related to programming directly, so please use another site for this. For example it’s can be https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

The Copper is not compatible with Mozilla version 56.0.1. I used Mozilla version 55.0.2 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla doesn't support some addons anymore with new realeses. You can check older version (55.0.0 was working for me). Then, You should unpicked auto-update from settings.